# Changing the color for selected item in spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

For some reason the text color of the selected item in my spinner is white. Here's the code for the Activity:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_categories);
arr_list_categories = manager.get_all_categories();
arr_list_categories_names = new ArrayList<String>();
// Loop through the Categories array
for (int i = 0; i < arr_list_categories.size(); i++) 
{
    Category curr_category = arr_list_categories.get(i); // Get the Category object at current position
    arr_list_categories_names.add(curr_category.getCategory_name()
            .toString()); // Add the name of the Category to the Names Array        
}
// Setting the Adapter, to display retrieved data in the Spinner
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr_list_categories_names);
// Setting the display source for the Spinner View
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Populating the Spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
// Registering for On Item Selected listener
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
```

And here's the XML of simple_spinner_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

The dropdown items appear in red, but not the selected item. I tried to change the textColor in XML to selector: `android:textColor="@drawable/spinner_text_color_selector"` and created this selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000"/><!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF0000"/><!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_selected="true"  android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <item android:color="#FF0000"/><!-- default -->
</selector>
```

But the selected item's text color was still white. So I tried to do this in OnItemSelectedListener:

```
TextView selected_tv = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
selected_tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Still white...

Why is it happening and how do I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: i Had same problem.i just change ArrayAdapter<String> (this) to ArrayAdapter<String> (classname.this).dont know ll work for u or not

Comment: I tried your code ..it's working fine .. shows red color for selected text.

Comment: @Sania Tried it, but it still shows me the text white...

Comment: @NibhaJain This is so strange... For some reason I see the text white, both on emulator and on actual device. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem - had a code that was affecting the color of the selected item. Silly me - didn't check the code I was bringing from my old project...

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView selected_tv = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
selected_tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

In this code, change in first line like this (Use TextView's id):

```
TextView selected_tv = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.selected_tv);
selected_tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```